# Android. Можно ли передавать строки из string.xml в комментарии?

Tags: java, android, строки, комментарии

Пишу комментарии к уже готовому коду. В итоге очень часто в методах указываются одни и те же параметры (поля таблицы, таблицы...).

Может возможно описать все таблицы в string.xml, а затем ссылаться на них в комментариях? Такое возможно?

Можете предложить более элегантное решение...

Comment: Попробуй вот эту штуку, мне кажется она может сойти за велосипед: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109203/android-studio-how-to-remove-update-the-created-by-comment-added-to-all-new-c

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-jsp-135444.html Все остальное - велосипеды.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Javadoc

```
{@value пакет.класс#поле}
```

> Отображает значение определенного поля static.

Т.е. можно создать Java class, туда записать строковые константы и ссылаться на них. И исключить данный класс из системы сборки.

Почитайте документацию Javadoc, там много всего, возможно подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно много одинаковых комментов, то можно сделать так:

```
public final class Constantaz {

    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEXT="Example text";

}
```

Потом можно достать так:

```
    textView.setText(Constantaz.EXAMPLE_TEXT);
```

Или к примеру для логов:

```
Log.e("TAG",Constantaz.EXAMPLE_TEXT);
```